# Is there any reason that bits in lsb of png changing by offset of 1 bit lower or higher

Tags: python, binary, png, python-imaging-library, steganography

I created a simple python script to save binary of text in the lsbs of png R G and B in a row. it's working good but sometimes one of the bits changing and while decription I am getting for example '`' instead 'a' and "e" instead "d" offset of 1 when related to ascii value

```
def encode(img, bin_str):
    new_img_data = []
    new_pixel = ()
    i = 0
    img_data = img.getdata()
    isDone = False
    for pixel in img_data:
        for color_part in pixel:
            if i < len(bin_str):
                binary = bin(color_part)[2:].zfill(8)
                binary = binary[:7] + bin_str[i]
                new_pixel += (int(binary, 2),)
                i += 1
            else:
                isDone = True
        if isDone is True:
            new_pixel = pixel

        new_img_data.append((new_pixel))
        new_pixel = ()
    new_img = Image.new(img.mode, img.size)
    new_img.putdata(new_img_data)
    return new_img


def decode(img, payload_len):
    img_data = img.getdata()
    solution = ""
    i = 0
    for pixel in img_data:
        for color_part in pixel:
            if i < payload_len:
                solution += bin(color_part)[2:].zfill(8)[7]
            i += 1
    print(solution)
    print(bin_to_string(solution))#convert 8 bits to number and takes the ascii of it
```

Comment: Can you provide an example input and its respective erroneous output? I can't replicate your results.

Comment: Sure for example, I encode 01100001(97 in decimal, ascii value of lowercase a) and the decode prints 01100000(96 in decimal ascii of `) offset in the last bit

Comment: Not enough information. `bin_str = '01100001'; slen = len(bin_str); decode(encode(img, bin_str), slen)` prints the same as `bin_str`. Either you're using an image which allows for a special case bug to express itself, or you do something else to what I did above, e.g., save the intermediate image to jpeg or something. You need to provide sufficient information to replicate your error.